# Spoofed forwarded email? Help with analyzing of DMARC report

Tags: email, email-spoofing, spf, dkim, dmarc

Why did this email get forwarded successfully? An XML report is below:

[image: easydmarc.com - Spoofed forwarded email?]

I simply cannot understand the delivery status, a transcript follows:

> This email has been automatically forwarded. Despite the fact that DMARC has failed, the email was still successfully delivered because DMARC had passed before the email was forwarded.

```
  <record>
    <row>
      <source_ip>209.85.220.41</source_ip>
      <count>1</count>
      <policy_evaluated>
        <disposition>none</disposition>
        <dkim>fail</dkim>
        <spf>fail</spf>
        <reason>
          <type>local_policy</type>
          <comment>arc=pass</comment>
        </reason>
      </policy_evaluated>
    </row>
    <identifiers>
      <header_from>vlastimilburian.cz</header_from>
    </identifiers>
    <auth_results>
      <dkim>
        <domain>emailprofi.seznam.cz</domain>
        <result>pass</result>
        <selector>szn20221014</selector>
      </dkim>
      <spf>
        <domain>smartstreamingott.com</domain>
        <result>none</result>
      </spf>
    </auth_results>
  </record>
```

**SPF** of this domain:

```
v=spf1 include:spf.seznam.cz -all
```

**DMARC** of this domain:

```
v=DMARC1; p=reject; sp=reject; rua=mailto:info@vlastimilburian.cz; ruf=mailto:info@vlastimilburian.cz; fo=0:1:d:s; aspf=s; adkim=r; pct=100; ri=86400
```

As I have no affiliation with *`smartstreamingott.com`*, I'd rather avoid any confusion.

Comment: Could you share the related email headers rather than a graphical illustration of the results?

Comment: The receiving server could be trusting _The Authenticated Received Chain_ (ARC) Protocol 
(RFC 8617) headers from Google. The SPF might have passed before forwarding, although a DKIM signature would have actually survived it.

Comment: In the worst case there could be forged authentication headers that should not be trusted. Hence, we need the full authentication & received headers in order to analyze this any further.

Comment: As stated by @EsaJokinen, it is impossible to definitively answer your questions without the headers of the email that seems to have been delivered. Of course, there's a good chance those headers are not in your posession as you might not know the final recipient address. Can you share which organization sent the XML file to you? It might help a little in determining the route of the email and the ultimate recipient.

Comment: @EsaJokinen Morning, thank you. So, without full headers it can't be determined. Ok. What a shame. I, of course, do not have that email, hence my suspicion on spoofing. Cheers

Comment: @Reinto `google.com!vlastimilburian.cz!1686009600!1686095999.xml` so Google. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the abstract of the DMARC rfc:

> Domain-based Message Authentication, Reporting, and Conformance
> (DMARC) is a scalable mechanism *by which a mail-originating
> organization can express domain-level policies and preferences for
> message validation, disposition, and reporting, that a mail-receiving
> organization **can use** to improve mail handling.*

DMARC provides a policy advice for receiving services to apply to emails that are not properly authenticating, or misalign. The XML reporting then allows the receiving service to return feedback to the domain owner on the emails it received where that domain is in the `FROM` header.

The provided XML report shows the feedback report from the receiving service, stating that although DKIM failed on alignment and an SPF record was absent on the `Return-Path` domain, the service opted to receive the email normally, providing the reason of local policy based on passing of ARC authentication. Possibly that of Google, since the reported sending server resolves back to a Google mail server.

Without the actual headers in the email that was delivered, it is impossible to tell where the mail flow originated, which hops were in between and based on which Authentication practices the ARC result was PASS.

**Just Speculation:**

Since both the ARC result and the Aggregate report were generated by Google, it is possible that the original recipient was part of a service connected to `smartstreamingott.com` where a forwarding mechanism caused a rewrite of the `Return-Path` header (a.k.a. `Envelope From`). And since Google will trust its own ARC results, the message is received even though DMARC ultimately failed.